# Failing to compile/run Rascal example code

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, rascal

I am trying to run the example code on [this part of the documentation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Concepts/SyntaxDefinitionAndParsing/SyntaxDefinitionAndParsing.html):

```
module demo::lang::Exp::Concrete::WithLayout::Syntax

layout Whitespace = [\t-\n\r\ ]*; 

lexical IntegerLiteral = [0-9]+;           

start syntax Exp 
  = IntegerLiteral          
  | bracket "(" Exp ")"     
  > left Exp "*" Exp        
  > left Exp "+" Exp        
  ;
```

However when running this I get an error being:
|unknown:///|: Java compilation failed due to package io.usethesource.vallang.type does not exist at 6, 36 with classpath [D:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar]
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/JavaCompilation/JavaCompilation.html|

It seems to be a missing dependency, even though I installed rascal following the instructions online. I have a 1.8 jdk, I have eclipse oxygen (reïnstalled all of them) I set my .ini file correctly as well. It is giving 0 errors on installation and such. I am trying to run it on a windows machine, could this be the problem. I have a second machine on which it is installed and it works just fine. So it is kind of a machine specific problem.
 (I only want to run on this windows machine since it is more powerful than my other machine. Rascal is quite heavy together with eclipse)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, rascal works on windows, no need to worry about that.

Is this on unstable or stable?

Maybe it would be a better idea to move this to a GitHub issue, as that format is better suited for this kind of question.

Comment: It is from the stable version. I had some troubles installing rascal the first time around on the windows machine. Then I did have errors. At some point I got frustrated and decided to start over, so I removed everything (rascal and eclipse) Then reinstalled all, now the errors are gone but this remains. Thanks for the tip I'll also post it on Github